# Why the "due" argument doesn't take the in account the time portion of the timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am currently developing a python script to manage tasks in Google Tasks. I would like to insert a task specifying both the date and the time. By going to the [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/tasks_v1.tasks.html#insert) page, this is what is written:

> "due": "A String", # Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp). Optional. The due date only records date information; the time portion of the timestamp is discarded when setting the due date. It isn't possible to read or write the time that a task is due via the API.

Am I looking at some old APIs docs, or do anyone know if there is a meaning behind this choice?

Also, in the app (and on the web version, a photo is reported below) it is possible to choose both and time, so why shouldn't we be able to do it programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

As the quote in your question implies, the `time` part of `due` is not supported in `Tasks API` (any `time` you provide will be ignored). And there's no intention to support this in the foreseeable future. Setting a task time is only supported on the user-interface.

#### Reference:

This functionality was previously requested on Issue Tracker, and Google's response was [the following](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149537960#comment3):

> We intentionally decided not to include the time features (apart from date) in the API. We're currently not actively improving the API.

Comment: Thanks for providing a reference. Even though it feels weird that they won't, at least, provide an explanation on why they made that choice.